# E 02/07/19-07:51:49.358 [-5] JMSListener exception : java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage cannot be cast to javax.jms.TextMessage

Tags: jms

```
E 02/07/19-07:51:49.358 [-5]  JMSListener exception : java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage cannot be cast to javax.jms.TextMessage
```

This is a ticky one. We put an xml message onto a queue and our code consumed it no problem. The next day, we put another xml message onto the same queue, and the same code threw this error.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to get more info out of what's actually happening, or if anyone else has had intermittent class cast exceptions like this with JMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that not all 'XML' messages are sent as JMS TextMessage. I've come across the same thing. Some applications will decide to send you the XML content as JMS BytesMessage (and put the text inside the byte array body). So make sure your sending is really sending you a TextMessage.

One way to see this is to stop your consumer and look at the queued messages with MQExplorer: the Named Property mcd.Msd should show jms_text if it was sent as proper MQ JMS TextMessage. If the data is received from a non-JMS application, the MQ format matters. If the format is MQFMT_STRING, the message is received as a JMS TextMessage. Otherwise, it is received as a JMS BytesMessage !

So either change your publisher to set the value of format to be MQFMT_STRING or change your consumer application to remove the cast to TextMessage and instead also accept BytesMessages and construct the text from the body's byte array.